# Sandwiches on Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday

Tags: inclusion-exclusion

15 students in a given class had a sanwich for lunch on Monday. 12 had a sandwich for lunch on Tuesday, and 9 had a sandwich for lunch on Wednesday. If 22 students had a sandwich at least once during these three days, what is the maximum number of students who could have eaten a sandwich on all three days?

So I've tried using the PIE, but I had problems figuring out the number of students who had sandwiches on Monday and Tuesday, Tuesday and Wednesday, and Wednesday and Monday... Wouldn't they be 12, 9, and 9 respectively? But apparently it is a wrong way to think about it as the answer is not correct. How would I solve this?

Comment: I suspect one cannot naively apply PIE, because it might not be possible to have $M\cap T = 12$, $T\cap W =  9$ and $W\cap M = 9$ all at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

To maximise the number of students who have eaten on all three days we will minimise the number of *new* people eating on every next day.

**Monday:** $15$ *(new students)*

**Tuesday:** $12$ *(students in total)* $=$ $x$ *(new students)* $+$ $n$ *(students who have eaten on Monday)*

**Wednesday:** $9$ (students in total) $=$ $22 - 15 - x$ (new students) $+$ $n$ *(students who have eaten on both Monday and Tuesday)*

$$\begin{cases}
x + n = 12\\
7 - x + n = 9
\end{cases}
\implies
\begin{cases}
x + n = 12\\
- x + n = 2
\end{cases}
\implies
n = 7$$

Therefore the maximum number of students who could have eaten a sandwich on all three days is $\textbf{7}$.